# How to dot subarrays in numpy?

Tags: numpy

I want to perform dot product between subarrays of two arrays.
Here's the code using loop.
Is there a more concise way to perform such operation without loops?

```py
result = numpy.empty(100)
A = numpy.random.randn(100, 1, 3)
B = numpy.random.randn(100, 3, 1)
for i in range(100):
    result[i] = A[i].dot(B[i])
```

Comment: `matmul` should produce a (100,1,1) array Try `A@B`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find out that `numpy.einsum()` would perfectly meet my need.

```
numpy.einsum('ijk,ikj->i', A, B)
```

Answer (score 0):

U made a better answer.
I use:

```
C = numpy.transpose(numpy.sum(A*numpy.reshape(B,(100,1,3)),2))
```